# Scrolling to cell in tableview based on a class value?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I've got a list of people, and I'm wanting if a button is pressed by the user for the tableview to scroll down to them in the list.

I've got an array of my People class which is holding unique IDs from firebase.

I found this:

```
  if let index = find([Array], setValueToSearchFor)
{
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 0)
    tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: true)
}
```

which is going through an array and I guess finding the index of a certain value in an array, but I can't just pop my UID into the 2nd param because it'd need to be something like person.UID but that doesn't make sense either.

Any idea on how to do this? I could possibly flag people when I'm making my array with a "if my uid == this person's UID, this is me" and then somehow use that flag, but I'm not sure where to go from there again. It seems more logical to use the actual UID stored in my Person class to check against my current UID since I've already got a way to identify who I am.

Comment: Show your array structure.

Comment: You want to find the index of an element in an array satisfying a predicate? If yes, use [`index(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1688966-index). Like: `let index = people.index { $0.id == idImLookingFor }`

Comment: @Arthur That's exactly what I needed.

Thanks both for the responses.